# MOC for CAT III missed approach segment

Tags: landing, ils, missed-approach, obstacle-clearance, pans-ops

Hello what is the MOC (minimum obstacle clearance) for missed approach segment for CAT III ILS minimum ?

Comment: I believe the answer to your question can be found in [Volume II of PANS-OPS doc 8168, beginning in chapter 6 - Missed Approach Segment](https://skybrary.aero/sites/default/files/bookshelf/5801.pdf) .  There are too many variables underlying your question that can be answered in a reasonable length answer.